# Unable to retrieve $sum from MongoDB aggregate

Tags: mongodb

In the query below, I successfully get the total length of all the `contribution` arrays, but I'm trying to also sum the `contribution_receipt_amount` field from each object in those arrays and its currently returning zero. What am I doing wrong?

```
 doc.aggregate(
        [
          { $unwind: '$contributions' },
          {
            $group: {
              _id: candidate.candidate_id,
              contributions: { $sum: 1 },
              total: { $sum: '$contribution_receipt_amount' }
            }
          }
        ],
        { allowDiskUse: true }
      )
```

The document looks like this:

```
{
    "_id" : "2015-05-31",
    "contributions" : [
    {
       "entity_type_desc" : "INDIVIDUAL",
       "contribution_receipt_amount" : 109.2,
     },
    {
       "entity_type_desc" : "INDIVIDUAL",
       "contribution_receipt_amount" : 105,
     }
  ]
},
{
    ...
}
```

And my output looks like this:

```
[ { _id: 'P60008885', contributions: 2, total: 0 } ]
```

Comment: Don't know. What is the actual output? `0` or `null`? Most likely the `contribution_receipt_amount` is a "string" instead of numeric. Show the output and a document you expect to actually show this value.

Comment: @NeilLunn I just edited the post with the output & document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The catch here is the field `contribution_receipt_amount` is the child of `contributions` document. so you should refer with `.` notation to access the sub document elements.

```
"contributions" : {
    "entity_type_desc" : "INDIVIDUAL",
    "contribution_receipt_amount" : 109.2
}
```

Here is the updated query

```
doc.aggregate(
        [
          { $unwind: '$contributions' },
          {
            $group: {
              _id: candidate.candidate_id,
              contributions: { $sum: 1 },
              total: { $sum: '$contributions.contribution_receipt_amount' }
            }
          }
        ],
        { allowDiskUse: true }
      )
```

As suggested by Neil

```
doc.aggregate(
        [          
          {
            $group: {
              _id: candidate.candidate_id,
              contributions: { $sum: 1 },              
              total: { $sum: {$sum: "$contributions.contribution_receipt_amount"} }
            }
          }
        ],
        { allowDiskUse: true }
      )
```

Comment: Or, `total: { $sum:{ $sum: { '$contributions.contribution_receipt_amount' } }`. One `$sum` for adding the array and one for the "grouping". You don't need the `$unwind`. Also `allowDiskUse: true` is a "hack". If you ever see the message, you're likely doing something else wrong that should be fixed instead.

Comment: @NeilLunn I didn't get the `allowDiskUse: true` part. Will you please little elaborate on that?

Comment: Don't use it. Add a sort or fix the query conditions if you see the message instead.

Comment: Much appreciated!